# Dynamic ng-model in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using Angular JS, I have this object

```
var pages = [ 
    { name: 'users', title : "Users" }, 
    { name: 'roles', title : 'Roles' }
];
```

I'm trying to create a page for user roles. For that I need 4 checkboxes for each page. Each page must have 4 rules. Access, show, edit, delete.

Displaying pages in a ng-repeat

```
<div ng-controller='PageCtrl'>
   <ul>
     <li ng-repeat='page in pages'>
        {{ page.title }}
        <input type="checkbox" name="access"> Access
        <input type="checkbox" name="show"> Show
        <input type="checkbox" name="edit"> Edit
        <input type="checkbox" name="delete"> Delete
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

So I need to pass those checkboxes values to the $scope. How can I bind a model for each checkbox?

Like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="access" ng-model='page.name+_access'> Access
```

Checkbox model name should start with page.name. Like users_access, users_show...

Comment: Bind them to a "page.access", "page.show", "page.edit", "page.edit" ? Dont mix your visiualization with your actual view model.

Comment: Meaning to say you want to know from the controller which checkboxes you have ticked?

Comment: Yes. I need those checkbox values in controller.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following syntax:

```
ng-model="page[page.name+'_access']"
```

But as a matter of fact, it looks one can move those groups into controller as well, then use another ng-repeat. Like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="PageCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat='page in pages'>{{ page.title }}
            <label ng-repeat="right in rights">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="page[page.name + '_' + right]" name="{{right}}" />{{right|capitalize}}</label>
            <button ng-click="log(page)">Log</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var module = angular.module('myAp', [])
    .controller('PageCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.pages = [{
        name: 'users',
        title: "Users"
    }, {
        name: 'roles',
        title: 'Roles'
    }];
    $scope.rights = ['access', 'show', 'edit', 'delete'];

    $scope.log = function (page) {
        console.log(page);
    }
}]).filter('capitalize', function() {
    return function (value) {
        return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
    };
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/e5ys0zaa/).

Comment: Thank you. This is great but what if the Log button is outside of ng-repeat? Because checkboxes are part of a big form. There are other form elements. I need to pass all elements to the controller with one click.

Comment: `Log` button does nothing - apart from showing you the changes in the model. ) Tap it after changing checkboxes' values, then check the console.

Comment: Ok. I think I got it :) Thank you.

Comment: the value in  $scope.log = function (page) {
        console.log(page);
    }
comes as undefined for dynamically declared ng-model